# Как можно сократить и улучшить это js код?

Tags: javascript, jquery, инспекция-кода

Здравствуйте, первый раз написал что-то на js, очень хотелось бы узнать можно ли как-то сократить код, что-то объединить или улучшить читаемость кода. И еще очень хотелось бы узнать: нормально ли объявлять такую кучу переменных или это указывает на криворукость?

Код: https://jsfiddle.net/2d46g2sc/

```js
var bgaArea = document.getElementById('name_area'),
  bgUsrInputBtn = document.getElementById('user_btn'),
  bgApplyBtn = document.getElementById('user_btn2'),
  bgReverseBtn = document.getElementById('user_btn3'),
  bgbgRandomBtn = document.getElementById('user_btn4'),
  infoArea = document.getElementById('show'),
  bgInput,
  a,
  bgRandom;

bgUsrInputBtn.onclick = function() {
  a = true;
  bgInput = prompt('Введите цвет(English or RGB only)', 'red');
  bgaArea.style.background = bgInput;
  infoArea.innerHTML = 'Вы выбрали: ' + bgInput;
  bgApplyBtn.style.visibility = 'visible';
  if (bgInput == null || bgInput == "") {
    infoArea.innerHTML = 'Вы ничего не выбрали';
    bgApplyBtn.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  };
};

bgbgRandomBtn.onclick = function() {
  a = false;
  bgRandom = '#' + (Math.random().toString(16)).substring(2, 8);
  bgaArea.style.background = bgRandom;
  bgApplyBtn.style.visibility = 'visible';
  infoArea.innerHTML = 'Вы выбрали: ' + bgRandom;
};


bgApplyBtn.onclick = function() {
  if (a == true) {
    document.body.style.background = bgInput;
    if (bgInput == null || bgInput == "") {
      alert('Не,не. Сначало надо выбрать цвет');
      bgReverseBtn.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else {
      bgReverseBtn.style.visibility = 'visible';
    };
  } else {
    document.body.style.background = bgRandom;
    bgReverseBtn.style.visibility = 'visible';
  };
};

bgReverseBtn.onclick = function() {
  document.body.style.background = '#fff';
  bgReverseBtn.style.visibility = 'hidden';
};

infoArea.innerHTML = 'Вы пока ничего не выбрали';
//list.appendChild(infoArea);
```

```css
button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#name_area {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  display: block;
  background-color: #000;
}
#user_btn,
#user_btn2,
#user_btn3,
#user_btn4 {
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 240px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em 0;
  background: transparent;
}
#user_btn2,
#user_btn3 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#user_btn3 {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="name_area"></div>
<button id="user_btn">Ввести цвет фона квадратика</button>
<button id="user_btn4">Случайный цвет</button>
<button id="user_btn2">Применить к фону</button>
<button id="user_btn3">Вернуть назад</button>
<div id="show"></div>
```

Comment: что делает этот код?

Comment: @Grundy съедает ресурс головного мозга))) а по теме, почти все можно разбить на методы. Вперед к функциональному программированию с чистыми функциями

Comment: при клике на user_btn просит ввести цвет и меняет фон блока name_area на введенное, есть проверка на пустое значение или отмену; при клике на user_btn4 меняет цвет фона блока name_area на случайный; при клике на user_btn2 применяет выбранный цвет (введенный или рандомный) к фону body; при клике на user_btn3 возвращает цвет фона body к белому. также цвет (введенный или рандомный) в текстовом формате выводиться в блочек show. по ссылке jsfiddle намного понятнее

Comment: @Сергей, это все должно быть в самом вопросе: [Политика относительно вопросов с инспекцией кода (code review)](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-code-review/1762) - посмотри каким требованиям должен удовлетворять вопрос с меткой [tag:инспекция-кода]

Comment: @Grundy я хотел описать, что делает код, но подумал что jsfiddle достаточно. Прошу прощения.

Comment: а для чего 
`list.appendChild(infoArea);`, если list ни где не инициализируется

Comment: @Василий Барбашев спасибо, похоже это кусок от старого кода остался